# Pinescript - need to use a label in a function to loop thru' and avoid overlapping text

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

here's the example of the code:

```
sDate = input.time(timestamp("12 22 2022 09:30:00 UTC-5"), title="Select significate High/Low")

nb_bars = ta.barssince(time == sDate)

nPrice = high[nb_bars]

calc_fun(nAC)  
   
  nformula25 = math.pow(math.sqrt(nPrice)+nAC+(0.25),2)  
  label_id25=label.new(bar_index+25,nformula25, text="45* - " + 
       str.tostring(nformula25), style=label.style_none, 
         textcolor=color.white)
  label.delete(label_id25[1])


for x = 0 to 5
   calc_fun(2*x)
```

but this creates an overlapping text. Thanks

used array.new_label ...which also resulted in same overlapping text

Answer (score 0):

why you need to call it in a for loop? Do you need to create 5 labels? `label.delete(label_id25[1])` deletes one of the labels 1 bar ago. If you need   it only on a last bar, then calculate loop just once (put inside `barstate.islastconfirmedhistory` block)

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

sDate = input.time(timestamp("12 22 2022 09:30:00 UTC-5"), title="Select significate High/Low")

nb_bars = ta.barssince(time == sDate)

nPrice = high[nb_bars]

calc_fun(nAC) =>
    nformula25 = math.pow(math.sqrt(nPrice)+nAC+(0.25),2)  
    label_id25=label.new(bar_index+25,nformula25, text="45* - " +  str.tostring(nformula25), style=label.style_none,  textcolor=color.white)

if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    for x = 0 to 5
        calc_fun(2*x)
```